# Can Tor Browser be used to download files from FTP site?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle

For experiment purpose, I have set up a FTP site in IIS 7.0. While trying to access FTP site via Tor Browser, I am getting error "550 Data channel timed out". I have made connection from Tor exit node which supports FTP port numbers 20 and 21.
Can anybody please highlight me on this problem? Is it that Tor Browser don't support FTP sites?
Note: I can easily visit this FTP using using normal browser.

Comment: There's a plan to remove native FTP support from Chrome and Firefox, but I'm unsure if this has happened yet. Is your non-TBB Firefox at the same version as your TBB? (To ensure you're comparing like for like.)

Comment: I am using Google chrome Version 44.0.2403.155 m (64-bit) and TBB 5.0.1.

Comment: Okay, so that implies Chrome still has native FTP support. You'd need to check whether the latest version of Firefox (on which TBB is based) still has this support.

Answer (score 1):

It is still possible to use FTP sites in TBB 5.0.1 I've tried it and it works.

In the Tor FAQ https://www.torproject.org/docs/faq.html.en#FTP the simple answer to

> How do I use my browser for FTP with Tor?

is

> Use Tor Browser.

Are you able to access any other FTP sites using TBB or are all the sites you've tried giving the same error messages? I ask because although some of the sites I tried gave me very reliable positive results a number of others often timed out with an error message.

Comment: I have not tried with other FTP sites. Can you please provide some FTP sites. I will give a try on those sites also. I also tried this particular site with FileZilla and got the same error

Comment: The site http://www.ftp-sites.org/ has some FTP servers. I tried some and some worked, while others didn't.